# How do i use exec in input("Do you want to like or dislike the video?: ") ((Python))

Tags: python, input, exec

I've written this program that I've been making for a couple of weeks, but I've ran into a small problem.

basically, when it asks input ("Do you want to like or dislike the video?: ") I do exec dislike but it doesn't let me use exec?

This is the error im getting
Do you want to like or dislike the video?: exec dislike

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MrCoInSanity\Desktop\python scripts\Youtube Bot\Youtube bot.py", line 40, in <module>
input("Do you want to like or dislike the video?: ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    exec dislike
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Could you provide some code and the actual error you are seeing....?

Comment: Do you want to like or dislike the video?: exec dislike

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MrCoInSanity\Desktop\python scripts\Youtube Bot\Youtube bot.py", line 40, in <module>
    input("Do you want to like or dislike the video?: ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    exec dislike
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

This exception commonly arises from input having `\r` in it. Given `value` is the variable holding the user's input, try with this before passing it to `exec`:

```
value = value.replace('\r', '')
```

Comment: Hey, can u please send me the code already done? here is my snippet                          Like = ('driver.find_element_by_class_name("like-button-renderer").click()            input("Do you want to like or dislike the video?: ")                                                 and sorry im really new to python

Comment: Add the relevant code to the question's body; and - this is problem & questions resolution site, not exactly a consulting service.